# Alinear horizontalmente una palabra con letras secuencialmente más pequeñas

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo hago para alinear una palabra horizontalmente con letras que secuencialmente son más pequeñas?

Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacer esto en *HTML+CSS*, pero no lo consigo.

Éste es mi código:

```css
.a{font-size: 1.3em;margin:auto;}
.b{font-size: 1em;margin:auto;}
.c{font-size: .9em;margin:auto;}
.d{font-size: .8em;margin:auto;}
.e{font-size: .7em;margin:auto;}
.f{font-size: .6em;margin:auto;}
.g{font-size:.5em ;margin:auto;}
.h{font-size: .4em;margin:auto;}
```

```html
<h1>
  <div class="a">M</div>
  <div class="b">i</div>
  <div class="c">L</div>
  <div class="d">e</div>
  <div class="e">t</div>
  <div class="f">t</div>
  <div class="g">r</div>
  <div class="h">a</div>......texto normal
</h1>
```

Comment: Por favor pon el código de lo que has intentado para que los demás podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico, con el suficiente nivel de detalle para permitir identificar una respuesta adecuada. Evita preguntar varias cosas distintas a la vez. Visita la página Cómo preguntar para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Comment: Ya esta corregida. Pensaba que había sido claro pero me equivoque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Otra opción un poco más genérica:

```css
.texto span:nth-child(1){
  font-size: 30px;
}
.texto span:nth-child(2){
  font-size: 28px;
}
.texto span:nth-child(3){
  font-size: 26px;
}
.texto span:nth-child(4){
  font-size: 24px;
}
.texto span:nth-child(5){
  font-size: 22px;
}
.texto span:nth-child(6){
  font-size: 20px;
}
.texto span:nth-child(7){
  font-size: 18px;
}
.texto span:nth-child(8){
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">
  <span>M</span><span>i</span>
  <span>l</span><span>e</span><span>t</span><span>r</span><span>a</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Una solución muy dinámica! Excelente

Comment: Sería mucho más dinámico hacerlo mediante JavaScript para que divida un texto en letras y a partir de un tamaño de fuente inicial, ir creando elementos span con una fuente disminuída. Luego, en el HTML sería tan fácil como: `<div secuential-font-size initial-font-size="30">Mi Letra</div>`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía estoy de acuerdo, pero se sale de las etiquetas que indica el _OP_, _html_ y _css_. No obstante podrías incluir la sugerencia como respuesta si lo estimas oportuno.

Answer (score 3):

Seguro que hay algo más eficiente y se pueda hacer con menos recursos.

Lo primero que se me ocurre sería hacerlo con bloques para cada letra `<span>(letra)</span>`.

Para un texto corto y estático se puede considerar una solución, para un texto más largo o dinámico, no se si sería lo más oportuno.

```css
.fs30 {font-size: 30px}
.fs25 {font-size: 25px}
.fs20 {font-size: 20px}
.fs15 {font-size: 15px}
```

```html
<p><span class="fs30">M</span><span class="fs25">i</span> <span class="fs20">l</span><span class="fs15">e</span><span class="fs20">t</span><span class="fs25">r</span><span class="fs30">a</span></p>
```

Comment: fasil y básico de realizar